# How to export categories description in Magento

Tags: magento, categories, file-descriptor

I need to get the category descriptions from a Magento database to use in a non-Magento shop. I have access to the Magentos admin and its database but can't see how to do this. From what I can tell, the descriptions are in the catalog_category_entity_text table. And that the category ID is in the entity_id field and the attribute_id is set to 44 for descriptions. But I can't find how to identify the ID's of the main categories. I'm using the following command. It does return all of the descriptions but I just need the descriptions for the parent categories. Is there a way to do that, preferably with mysql but through admin if that is easier.

```
    select ct.value from catalog_category_entity_text ct left join catalog_category_entity_varchar cv on ct.entity_id = cv.entity_id 
     where ct.attribute_id = 44 and cv.attribute_id = 41
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to get the categories with :

```
parent_id = 0
```

In the query. Not sure in which table it is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I searched all of the tables for that column name but there aren't any.

Comment: should be in some EAV table?